# How to add a button on a tree inside a form in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to add a button to the order_line tree in the sale form, I added like this:

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='price_subtotal']" position="after">
    <button name="%{action_view_wizard}d" string="" type="action" icon="fa-archive" attrs="{'invisible':[('product_id','=', False)]}"/>
</xpath>
```

And the wizard is defined

```
<record id="check_stock" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale_warehouse.check_stock_wizard</field>
    <field name="model">sale_warehouse.check_stock_wizard</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Stock by warehouse">
            <group col="1">
                <field name="stock" nolabel="1"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button string="Close" class="btn-default" special="cancel" />
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="action_view_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Stock by warehouse</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">sale_warehouse.check_stock_wizard</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="check_stock"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

The button is added ok but its load as disable and so when clicked the wizard is no call, if I take the button out the tree the wizard is called ok, but I need to be call from the order_line becouse I need to pass the context with product_id of the line to get the stock in each warehouse.

I'm using odoo10.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]/field[@name='order_line']/tree position="inside">
    <button name="open_view_wizard" string="" type="object" icon="fa-archive" attrs="{'invisible':[('product_id','=', False)]}"/>
</xpath>
```

And then add the function **open_view_wizard** to your **sale** model, and open the wizard inside that function: for example (you probably need to change this code a little bit).

```
def open_view_wizard(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

            return {
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'res_model': 'sale_warehouse.check_stock_wizard',
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'context': context
            }
```